# Unable to find xpath in salesforce lightning due to dynamic locator

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to do automation testing using Selenium web driver. I am facing an issue while finding xpath of any element in salesforce lightning. Element Ids and classes are getting randomly generated so not able to get relative path. Pls help.

```
<div class="col-sm-12"><div class="vehicle-info"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><div class="slds-text-heading--medium">Kjøretøyinformasjon:</div></div></div><br><fieldset><div class="row" style="margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;"><div class="row"><span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id217" class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><b>Registreringsdato:&nbsp;</b><span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id219">26.02.2019</span></span> <span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id220" class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><b>Registreringsnummer:&nbsp;</b><span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id222"></span></span> <span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id223" class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><b>VIN:&nbsp;</b><span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id225">ABCDE0000K1234567</span></span></div><div class="row"><span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id227" class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><b>Kjørekjøpspris:&nbsp;</b> 25.000,00 kr</span> <span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id229" class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><b>Policy solgt dato:&nbsp;</b><span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id231">26.02.2019</span></span> <span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id232" class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><b>kilometer/KM:&nbsp;</b><span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id234">1&nbsp;000</span></span></div><div class="row"><span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id236" class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><b>Opprett:&nbsp;</b><span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id238">TCS</span></span> <span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id239" class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><b>Modell:&nbsp;</b><span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id241">i10</span></span></div><div class="row"><span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id243" class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><b>Drivstoff type:&nbsp;</b><span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id245">Bensin</span></span> <span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id246" class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><b>Motorkapasitet (cc):&nbsp;</b><span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id248">1&nbsp;318</span></span> <span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id249" class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><b>Transmisjonstype:&nbsp;</b><span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id251">Manuell girkasse</span></span></div><div class="row"><span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id253" class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><b>Trim:&nbsp;</b><span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id255">Elegance</span></span> <span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id256" class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><b>Kjøretøybeskrivelse:&nbsp;</b>1.3 i-VTEC 102hk</span> <span id="j_id0:j_id9:j_id214:j_id215:j_id259" class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><b>Kjøretøytype:&nbsp;</b>Cars</span></div></div></fieldset></div></div>
```

My page is in multilingual so not able to get element xpath with respect to text. I want to find the xpath of "trim" label.

Comment: Please add the html for the element

Comment: @SameerArora , Hi Sameer, I update my query.

Comment: Please add the html in a code block.